# Can't use String.prototype.match as function for Array.some?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This doesn't work:

```
var s = '^foo';
console.log(['boot', 'foot'].some(s.match));

Uncaught TypeError: String.prototype.match called on null or undefined
```

But this does:

```
var s = '^foo';
console.log(['boot', 'foot'].some(function(i) { return i.match(s) }));
```

Why is this? I imagine somehow the `String.prototype.match` function is too "primitive" or something, but why exactly? Since I'm not using ES2015, the second version seems quite verbose. Is there an alternative?

EDIT

When I wrote the above, I actually got it backwards compared to my actual need, which was matching one string against a number of regexes. But thanks to the great answers and comments below, I get it: `[/^foo/, /^boo/].some(''.match, 'boot')`.

Comment: Don't you mean `i.match(s)`?  Not that it matters really.

Comment: `['boot', 'foot'].some(/./.test, /^foo/)` works as expected since test() lives on the regexp, which can be passed in to some(), whereas you can't call the per-item string-based match() method without a wrapper on the `[].some()` callback. so, if you were using `"".match()` to `filter/some/every`, simply use `/./.test()` instead and pass the regexp pattern as the 2nd argument to the array method.

Comment: @dandavis That's pretty interesting, why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function value in Javascript does not bring its object along with it.  The value of `s.match` is a plain function value, with no knowledge that you happened to find it attached to `s`. In fact, no matter what String you access it through, it's always the *same* function value:

```
"foo".match === "bar".match 
//= true
```

When you *call* a function through an object, Javascript sets `this` to that object for the duration of the function call. But as soon as anything comes between retrieving the function value and calling it, any object association is lost.

You can create a function that *does* remember a specific `this` value using `bind`, as in @Felix King's answer.  `someFunction.bind(someObject)` has approximately the same meaning as `function(arg1, arg2,...) { return someObject.someFunction(arg1, arg2,...); }`, but it automatically handles the number of parameters properly.

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** The value of `this` is determined by how the function is **called**! (exception: bound and arrow functions)

If you pass `s.match` to `.some`, then the function will be called with `this` set to the global object (e.g. `window`) not the string it "belongs" to.

I.e. it would be equivalent to this:

```
String.prototype.match.call(window, 'foo')
```

This cannot work because `this` has to refer to a string object.

You could solve this by *binding* the function to a specific `this` value:

```
['boot', 'foot'].some(s.match.bind(s));
```

---

Learn more about `this`:

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [You Don't Know JS: `this` or That?](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md)
- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Same result but you could also refer to the function on the String prototype: `['boot', 'foot'].some(String.prototype.match.bind(s));` Seems more "pure" to me but who knows.